# $ \sum_n a_nx_n \le c \sum_n b_nx_n $

Tags: inequality

Let $(a_n)_{n}$ and $(b_n)_{n}$ two sequence of positive reals which sum up to $1$. Does there exist a constant $c$ such that
$$
\sum_n a_nx_n \le c \sum_n b_nx_n   
$$
for all $x=(x_1,x_2,...) \in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $a_n=2^{-n}$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $b_{2n-1}=2^{-2(2n-1)}=a_{2n-1}^2$, and let

$$b_{2n}=a_{2n}+(a_{2n-1}-b_{2n-1})=2^{-2n}+2^{-(2n-1)}-2^{-2(2n-1)}\;.$$

If $x_{2n-1}=1$ and $x_k=0$ for $k\ne 2n-1$, then

$$\sum_ka_kx_k=a_{2n-1}=2^{2n-1}b_{2n-1}=2^{2n-1}\sum_kb_kx_k\;.$$

Comment: Then, doesn't $c=1$ work for your example?

Comment: @Clement: No. For each $n$, $c$ must be at least $2^{2n-1}$. But I see now why you thought so: I inadvertently left off a factor in front of the last sum.

Comment: After the edit, I see :) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yep it works, thank you; I will post the question with the additional constraint on small-oh in a separate question

Comment: @Nduccio: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=2^{-n}$ and $b_n=2\cdot3^{-n}$. Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=1
$$
yet if $x=\{\underbrace{0,0,0,\dots,}_{\text{$k$ zeros}}1,0,0,0,\dots\}$, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n=2^{-k-1}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nx_n=2\cdot3^{-k-1}
$$
so we would need $c\ge\frac34\left(\frac32\right)^k$. Thus, there is no $c$ that satisfies the inequality for these sequences.