# $ \sum_n a_nx_n \le c \sum_n b_nx_n $ with $b_n=o(a_n)$

Tags: inequality

Let $(a_n)_{n}$ and $(b_n)_{n}$ two sequence of positive reals which sum up to $1$ and $b_n=o(a_n)$. Does there exist a constant $c$ such that
$$
\sum_n a_nx_n \le c \sum_n b_nx_n   
$$
for all $x=(x_1,x_2,...) \in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$?

A variant of this question (or better, the same one without the small-oh constraint) has a positive answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907803/sum-n-a-nx-n-le-c-sum-n-b-nx-n/1907813#1907813).

Comment: Wasn't it $a_n=o(b_n)$ you wanted?

Comment: No, $a_n=o(b_n)$ is the easy case as you can "definitively" choose $c=1$ so that it is enough to fix small values of $n$

Comment: [My example](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1907823) from your previous question works here, too, since $2\cdot3^{-n}=o\left(2^{-n}\right)$.

Comment: I posted the question before your answer sorry; anyway, you're right! :)

Comment: @Nduccio Are you (a) waiting for answers; (b) no longer interested in this question as it's settled by an answer to your previous one?

Comment: You're right Clement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

Take any $(a_n)_n$ satisfying the requirements such that $a_1 < \frac{1}{2}$; and let $(c_n)_n$ be any sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty c_n = 1$ and $c_n=o(a_n)$ when $n\to\infty$. Fix any $A>1$, and define $(b_n)_n$ by 
$$
b_1 = 1-\frac{1}{A}, \qquad b_n= \frac{1}{A}c_{n} \text{ for } n>1.
$$

Then $b_n = o(a_n)$ by construction, and, setting $$x_n = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } n=1\\ 1 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n = 1-a_1 > \frac{1}{2}
$$
while 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x_n = \frac{1}{A}.
$$
Since $A$ is arbitrary, this shows that no absolute constant $c$ can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $a_n=\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$ and $b_n=\frac{2}{3^{n+1}}$. Suppose that there exists $c$ such that
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}{a_nx_n}\le c\sum_{n\ge 1}{b_nx_n}
$$
and choose $x$ made by all zeros except the $k$-th component $1$. Then we conclude
$$
\frac{2^k}{3^{k+1}} \le c \frac{2}{3^{k+1}}\implies c\ge 2^{k-1}
$$
for all $k$, which is impossible.